# Asp - Display data by date

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to display this data in order of LastActivityDate

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="usage_info_DS" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/ASPNetDB.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT aspnet_Users.UserName, aspnet_Users.LastActivityDate, aspnet_Membership.LastLoginDate FROM (aspnet_Membership INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON aspnet_Membership.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId) WHERE (aspnet_Membership.UserId <> 100) AND (aspnet_Membership.UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles WHERE (RoleId = (SELECT RoleId FROM aspnet_Roles WHERE (RoleName = ?)))))">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="?" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Cheers
Ross

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="usage_info_DS" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/ASPNetDB.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT aspnet_Users.UserName, aspnet_Users.LastActivityDate, aspnet_Membership.LastLoginDate FROM (aspnet_Membership INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON aspnet_Membership.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId) WHERE (aspnet_Membership.UserId <> 100) AND (aspnet_Membership.UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles WHERE (RoleId = (SELECT RoleId FROM aspnet_Roles WHERE (RoleName = ?))))) order by aspnet_Users.LastActivityDate">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="?" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an [order by clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) in your sql statement. So your query should be:

```
SELECT 
aspnet_Users.UserName, 
aspnet_Users.LastActivityDate, 
aspnet_Membership.LastLoginDate 
FROM 
        (aspnet_Membership INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON aspnet_Membership.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId) 
WHERE   
        (aspnet_Membership.UserId <> 100) 
        AND (aspnet_Membership.UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles 
                                          WHERE (RoleId = (SELECT RoleId FROM aspnet_Roles WHERE (RoleName = ?)))))
order by 2;
```

2 is specifying the column to apply order by, you can also use column name `aspnet_Users.LastActivityDate`

**EDIT:**

If you want to get the latest date at the top of the result set use:

```
order by 2 desc;
```

Comment: Thanks that never worked, do you think it could be because the date format is: 26/06/2012 19:05:20

Comment: It should work, what is the column type in the SQL Server, is it DateTime ? and if you want the latest date to come up, use `order by desc`

Comment: It is in Date/Time format, I've tried the ordr by desc still no luck.

Comment: 26/06/2012 19:05:20
01/09/2011 16:59:16
11/10/2011 08:44:00
28/05/2012 16:40:33
26/06/2012 17:02:58